Issue with accessing Gatsby application running in Docker container
I'm trying to set up Docker for my Gatsby v5 application located in a folder structure like this:
main-folder
|_ backend (Docker setup working fine)
|_ frontend (trying to set up Docker for this)

In frontend directory, I've created two files:

Dockerfile

FROM node:20.11.1-alpine as node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli
RUN npm install

COPY . .


docker-compose.yml

version: "3.9"

services:
  node:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0
    tty: true

When I run docker-compose up, I get the following output:
You can now view main-folder in the browser.
⠀
  Local:            http://localhost:8000/
  On Your Network:  http://172.18.0.2:8000/
⠀
View GraphiQL, an in-browser IDE, to explore your site's data and schema
⠀
  Local:            http://localhost:8000/___graphql
  On Your Network:  http://172.18.0.2:8000/___graphql

However, when I try to access http://localhost:8000/ in my browser, I get no response. Strangely, accessing http://172.18.0.2:8000/ works fine.
I want to access my application at http://localhost:9000/ and replace gatsby develop with npm start, but whenever I make changes in docker-compose.yml, the application compiles and runs, but I still can't access it at http://localhost:8000/.
I've checked Docker logs and inspected the setup but haven't found any errors. Any insights into why I can't access my Gatsby application at http://localhost:8000/ would be greatly appreciated.

The second ports: number needs to match the port the process is actually using.  If the server process is listening on port 8000 (as per the startup logs) but you want to use host port 9000, then you need ports: ['9000:8000'].

I did this as well but still same!!

Answering my own question as after spending several hours, blogs and personal network feedback, below is issue why i was unable to see my gatsby v5 in browser
Reference Link -> https://valenciandigital.com/insights/why-containerize-your-gatsby-application (This link helped me resolve all my issues for Gatsby dockerizing app)
In my Dockerfile i added this line at end (Rest code remains same as posted in question)
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

In my docker-compose.yml i updated as below (Deleted all code which was provided as part of question)
frontend:
  build:
    context: ./frontend
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ./frontend/src:/app/src
  ports:
    - 8000:8000

In my package.json
I updated by code from
"scripts": {
  "develop": "gatsby develop"
}

to;
"scripts": {
  "develop": "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8000"
}

PN: you can also define port and host in env files and consume it dynamically for builds, i did like
"scripts": {
  "develop": "gatsby develop -H ${GATSBY_HORT} -p ${GATSBY_PORT}"
}

I also have workable code available on https://github.com/akshayshrivastav866/news-aggregator/ so that if required one can take it as a reference.
